# Fast api TestClient post list of files

Tags: python, python-requests, fastapi, webtestclient

**I am trying to test fastapi router that get List of files. In html request using JS its working but I need to test it. I am using TestClient from fastapi, when I am trying so send list I get status code 422 so I go which documentry and try** `dict` **but than I get list of only 1 file.**

## router

```
@router.post('/uploadone')
async def upload_file(response: Response,files:List = File(...)):
    try:

        properties = json.loads(files[len(files)-1])
        check_file_type(files[:len(files)-1])
```

## test

```
def test_uploadone(self):
    with open('upload_data/system_test/properties.json', 'rb') as file1:
         json_file = json.load(file1)
    with open('upload_data/system_test/heatmap1.csv', 'rb') as file:
         body = file.read()
         response = self.client.post('/actions/uploadone',
                                        files={'files':('design_matrix1.csv', body),'json': 
                                              ('prop.json', json.dumps(json_file))})
         self.assertTrue(response.status_code == 200)
```

**thanks for helping**

Answer (score 1):

I had problems testing [uploading](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#multiple-file-uploads) a list of files, I achieved it using a [list format](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files) instead of a dict

```
files = [
    ("parameter", ("file1.txt", BytesIO(b"aaa"))),
    ("parameter", ("file2.txt", BytesIO(b"bbb"))),
]

response = self.test_client.post("/api/upload", files=files)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you should also add the `multipart/form-data` in the `files`.

response = self.client.post('/actions/uploadone',
files={'files':('design_matrix1.csv', body, "multipart/form-data"),'json':
('prop.json', json.dumps(json_file))})

See

https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/43327/how-to-send-a-ldquo-multipart-form-data-rdquo-with-requests-in-python

**NOTE**

I also suggest you to split the data and the file parts, into two separate dictionaries, as in the example linked above